# Rewrite double nested for loop as a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following Java method:

```
public List<GrantedAuthority> toAuthorities(Set<Role> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    if (null != roles) {
        for (Role role : roles) {
            for (Permission permission : role.getPermissions()) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + permission.getLabel()));
            }
        }
    }

    return authorities;
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite it using Java 8 streams. My best attempt thus far:

```
public List<GrantedAuthority> toAuthorities(Set<Role> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    if (null != roles) {
        roles.stream().filter(role -> ???).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    return authorities;
}
```

But I'm at a loss as to what I put in the stream filter (substituting `???`)...any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `flatMap` and `map` instaead as :

```
if (null != roles) {
    authorities = roles.stream()
         .flatMap(role -> role.getPermissions().stream()) // Stream<Permission>
         .map(permission -> 
                 new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + permission.getLabel())) // Stream<SimpleGrantedAuthority>
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In the `for` loop code, you are not filtering out/in any iteration based on a condition and iterating throughout the lists, hence you don't require a `filter` here.

---

And using the above your complete method could be written as :

```
public List<GrantedAuthority> toAuthorities(Set<Role> roles) {
    return roles == null ? new ArrayList<>() : roles.stream()
            .flatMap(role -> role.getPermissions().stream())
            .map(permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + permission.getLabel()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or as [suggested by shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979975/rewrite-double-nested-for-loop-as-a-java-8-stream#comment92866651_52980017), with method references this could be transformed as :

```
return roles == null ? new ArrayList<>() : roles.stream()
        .map(Role::getPermissions)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(Permission::getLabel)
        .map("ROLE_"::concat)
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: not sure this will compile because of generics invariance, OP wants to return a `List<GrantedAuthority>`, this will generate  `List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>`

Comment: You can return `Collections.emptyList()`.

Comment: @Eugene I think it would infer the right type. If not, you could always add a type witness.

Comment: @shmosel right, but you need that type witness here, otherwise it will not work

Comment: @Eugene I don't think so. Did you test it?

Comment: If you prefer method references, you could do `roles.stream().map(Role::getPermissions).flatMap(Collection::stream).map(Permission::getLabel).map("ROLE_"::concat).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)`.

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer (+1) -- what are the `flatMap` and `map` methods each returning in your example?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Updated in the code as comments as well. They would be returning `Stream<Permission>` and `Stream<SimpleGrantedAuthority>` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in a single chain, not sure how readable that is to you though:

```
public static List<GrantedAuthority> toAuthorities(Set<Role> roles) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(roles)
            .orElse(Collections.emptySet())
            .stream()
            .flatMap(r -> r.getPermissions().stream())
            .map(Permission::getLabel)
            .map("ROLE_"::concat)
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: If you're using `Optional`, probably cleaner to do `Optional.ofNullable(roles).orElse(Collections.emptySet()).stream()`

Comment: I gave this a try with Java9+, it could further be simplified as `return Optional.ofNullable(roles).stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(Role::getPermissions)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(Permission::getLabel)
                .map("ROLE_"::concat)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @nullpointer right, if only we had `stream`... but even the simplified version reads a lot harder than what the OP has in place *for some* people at least.. still this is nice!